# Relationship between three tables in MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database, ms-access-2013

So basically these are my tables :

[image]

When I'm adding records to Table3, I want Access to check at the database level that the pair (C,A) of the record (D,C,A) that is going to be added is a valid one by looking up its corresponding B attribute in Table2 and ensuring that the resulting (B,A) pair is a valid one ( ie exists in Table1 ). However I'm clueless right now and don't know how to establish such a relationship in Access without breaking the 3NF that I have on my database.

Of course this can be done in the frontend, but I prefer a solution at the database level as I'm sure I can force this integrity check through a relationship.

EDIT :

I'm adding some details about the functional dependencies if it may help. As already stated, one can safely assume that those tables are already in 3NF. The only functional dependencies (except of course the ones resulting from transitivity) are :

D,C -> A

C -> B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoricaly, you can do it with a view / query containing Table1 and Table2.
As this query will be used only for data integrity (and not to store datas), you won't destroy your 3NF model.

Unfortunately, Access can't create a relationship with referencial integrity within a query, but only a "normal relationship". With that, you can delete a record in Table1 without warning, even if it destroys the referencial integrity.

Comment: I guess my only choices then are : leaving it as it is, replacing the B attribute by C in Table1 (which would then add redundancy), or making the pair (C,B) a primary key in Table2 and adding a B attribute in Table3 (but this would destroy even the 2NF). I'll give the second solution a try. Thanks ! (can't upvote at the moment)